# Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.'Function' is from 'dart:core'.onPressed: selectHandler

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import './questions.dart';
    import './answer.dart';
    
    void main() {
    runApp(AskMe());
    }
    
    class AskMe extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _AskMeState();
    }
    }
    
    class _AskMeState extends State<AskMe> {
    var _next_ques = 0;
    
    void _Response() {
        setState(() {
        _next_ques += 1;
        });
        print(_next_ques);
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var questions = ["What is your Name ?", "What is your favourite color ?"];
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Ask Me"),
            ),
            body: Column(
            children: [
                Questions(questions[_next_ques]),
                Answer(_Response),
                Answer(_Response),
                Answer(_Response),
            ],
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

questions.dart

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
        class Questions extends StatelessWidget {
        final String questions;
        Questions(this.questions);
        
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text(
                questions,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            );
        }
        }
```

answer.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
    final Function selectHandler;
    
    Answer(this.selectHandler);
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: Text("Question 1"),
            onPressed: selectHandler,
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

The above code is for basic app that consists of 3 buttons for the questions shown as textview and clicking on button will display next question. The issue i'm facing is while making custom dart function in answer.dart i'm not able to call the pointer to the function _Response which is present in main.dart as it gives the error mentioned in the title. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define function type like this:

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() selectHandler;
  ...
```